# Hotspotshield CLI returns "root FS device can't be found" when install on headless server

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, virtual-machine, vpn

I am trying to run hotspotshield cli on a headless server. It won't allow me to connect and return "root FS device can't be found" every time. Working fine on my local machine.
I am using ubuntu 22.04

I tried looking for the solution. No success so far.